# How to save data into single value of multiples buttons in android and save that total value in firebase?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I have five buttons on an activity and on every button click i want to save data shown/written on button say "10",on other button "20" etc.into arraylist or list and than add(+) them every time any button is clicked and than store them on single value and when sublit button is clicked than the total single value is saved into firebase database as signle child data.

[image]

Comment: answering  me in coding example would be helpful

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: yes i have saved data into firebase database from two edit texts that was easy

Comment: it is easy task. just get text of button .. convert that text to integer and Sum them. you don't need any arraylist for this

Comment: but i want to save every button click value into single variable and than save it into firebase database as a single detail of child

Comment: anybody please help in the form of code kindly

Comment: `int clicked_number = Integer.parseInt(btnTen.getText().ToString());` use this to get number on each button.

Comment: thankyou Ali Ahmad.Now how to save each buttons value to single variable also with addition of each button click value into single value their total and than save that value to fire base database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will working for you.

```
ArrayList<Integer> total =  new ArrayList();

int totalCount = 0;


        button10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                total.add(10);
            }
        });

        button20.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                total.add(20);
            }
        });

        button50.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                total.add(50);
            }
        });

        button100.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                total.add(100);
            }
        });

        button500.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                total.add(500);
            }
        });

        button1000.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                total.add(1000);
            }
        });

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for(int i = 0; i < total.size();i++){
                    totalCount = totalCount + total.get(i); //total value or Output
                }
            }
        });
```